# Reacting to launchservicesd error messages

Tags: console

I am able to observe a particular error message from `launchservicesd` via Console.app that I would like to use to trigger a script:

[image]

However, I'm not sure from what source Console.app is displaying this message. (My guess is that it's coming from the `launchservicesd` process's `stderr`, but I haven't been able to confirm this.) How might I observe these messages from a context in which I can react to them?

Motivation: I'm setting up a mac to auto answer and display incoming skype calls, which works, but unfortunately the screen saver prevents the video from being seen. I can use applescript to exit the screen saver, but need an event to trigger the script.